# How to check iOS 11 installed device supported ARKit?

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I am currently working on `ARKit` based application. I need to check `ARKit` supported device.

I have two `UIViewController`s

1)`ARKit` View Controller 
2) Non-`ARKit` View Controller.

I have to set one of one view controller based on device support.

Currently I am checking below code. But that is not working on some of devices which do not support `ARKit` but has iOS 11.

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            arProfileClosetController = THARClosetViewController(nibName: THARClosetViewController.className, bundle: nil)
        } else {
            arProfileClosetController = THNonARClosetViewController(nibName: THNonARClosetViewController.className, bundle: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check this property at runtime: [ARConfiguration.isSupported](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arconfiguration/2923553-issupported)

```
if (ARConfiguration.isSupported) {
    arProfileClosetController = THARClosetViewController(nibName: THARClosetViewController.className, bundle: nil)
} else {
    arProfileClosetController = THNonARClosetViewController(nibName: THNonARClosetViewController.className, bundle: nil)
}
```